# Data sent to a WCF REST service wouldn't go to the Stream input parameter

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, rest

I'm currently struggling with implementing file upload to a WCF REST service.

The client does the following:

```
void uploadFile( string serverUrl, string filePath )
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.
        Create( serverUrl );
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
    request.SendChunked = true;
    request.Timeout = 60000;
    request.KeepAlive = true;

    using( BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader( 
        File.OpenRead( filePath ) ) ) {

        request.ContentLength = reader.BaseStream.Length;
        using( Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream() ) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while( true ) {
                int bytesRead = reader.Read( buffer, 0, buffer.Length );
                if( bytesRead == 0 ) {
                    break;
                }
                stream.Write( buffer, 0, bytesRead );
            }
        }
    }

     HttpWebResponse result = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
     //handle result - not relevant
 }
```

where `serverUrl` is "http://localhost:/Service1.svc/UploadFile".

The WCF REST service has a method with the following signature:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="POST")]
string UploadFile(System.IO.Stream fileData);
```

which is implemented as follows:

```
public string UploadFile(System.IO.Stream fileData)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while( true ) {
        int readAmount = fileData.Read( buffer, 0, buffer.Length );
        if( readAmount == 0 ) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

When I start the service and run the client code the following happens.

The client starts the while-loop, control enters the service method and the server starts the while-loop. `Read` on the server returns zero, control falls through and the server method returns. Meanwhile the client gets an exception trying to call `Write()` - "Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

So to me it looks like the file data that I try to stream into the request just doesn't map onto the server method parameter. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

possibly try a different content-type? "application/octet-stream"

The code looks right to me. Does the client part read the entire file in or does it have problems? Test that first. Use fiddler to see what is actually going over the wire to the service.

If the client can read in the entire file to the buffer, try sending it all at once

request.Write(entireFileBuffer, 0, entireFileLength);
request.close();

instead of chunking it.

Comment: I tried all that and it doesn't help much. Without Fiddler it doesn't work, client now throwing an exception "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.", the request reaches the server and the server behavior is the same as previously . With Fiddler I get HTTP 502 Bad Gateway on the client and the request doesn't reach the server, the request looks reasonable in Fiddler.

Comment: has localhost been changed to point somewhere else (via hosts file)? What if you host the service on another machine? Are you trying to go through any proxies? Can you use Fiddler to manually send a request to the service. If so, does it work? Can your client get to a normal operation on the service like TestMethod()? Try it without the streaming.